# How to make scrollable UIView without using UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, scrollable

Is there any way to make a normal UIView scrollable without using UIScrollView?

Answer (score 3):

You could, by overriding `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` and associate methods, but you'd have to implement an equivalent to `contentOffset`, `contentSize`, and probably have some sort of `contentView` which moves within your own scroll view. You'd also have to implement all of the momentum physics, which would potentially be very time consuming. Then you've got all of the interaction between gestures and scrolling (e.g. some touch events are "cancelled" if you hold your finger down then start scrolling, this is all handled for you automatically by the built-in UIKit classes).

It's certainly possible, but it'd be a hell of a lot of work, so unless you had a really, really good reason to build your own there's no point.

Comment: Thank you Nick, but i do have reason: i have objects with tags placed on an UIView (that i want to scroll) and i handle events according to the objects tags. The UIScrollView does not give me an option to get the touched object tag, does it? At least i could not find it.

Comment: `UIScrollView` inherits from `UIView`, so you can still use `-viewWithTag:` on a scroll view. You'll need to describe what you're trying to actually achieve in order to get a more helpful answer, since your current question has now been answered.

Comment: Well it's pretty simple: what actually i want to achieve is to make a UIView scrollable without using UIScrollView. I need to be able to browse my UIView beyond the edges. Like let's say i make a UIView 4096x3072, put objects on it and use the objects to make actions, depending on the object touched. Hmm can't add anything, i think it's self explaining.

Comment: Anyway i see it's not possible, pity. So i think we need to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to state what you're trying to achieve, because probably you can do it with [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) and also implementing the [UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate). I have done some very fancy things with scroll views quite easily just by implementing the delegate and putting my additional code in there.

Comment: Sorry, no, with UIScrollView i can't. The touches are either swallowed by the uiscrollview or too slow to react.